# Error when trying to define a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the intersection of two lists, but I'm getting this error:

> Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file right_characterD1D2.py on line 7

but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: Line 7 contains a `‘` character instead of a `'` single quote.

Comment: Did you copy Line 7 directly, or retype it?

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your original question. All along you've been leading us to believe that `b = ['ma', 'is', 'n ']` was the actual Line 7. Obviously, one of the list items contains `â`, but you didn't include that vital data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One of your items contains a `'â'` character, and that's a non-ascii character. Use `unicode` instead of `str`:

```
b = [u'ma', u'is', u'n', u'â' ...]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
b = ['ma', 'is', 'n']
```

You missed a quote before `ma`, and instead inserted `‘`

**EDIT**

Add this on the beggining of your file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: It should be closed with "]"(if that's not a typo).

Comment: If not, try inserting double quotes instead of single.

Comment: The problem is that he is using `str`, while the character is non-ascii. He should be using `unicode`